# DB2 rollforward fails

Tags: restore, db2, db2-luw

I get the following error when I try to do a point in time recovery

> [inst20@localhost ~]$ db2 rollforward database sample2 to
>   2018-09-01-15.16.00 and stop SQL4970N  Rollforward recovery stopped on
>   the database named "SAMPLE2" because the rollforward utility cannot
>   reach the specified stop point (end-of-log or point-in-time) on the
>   following database partitions: "0".

The rollforward operation follows a restore operation.
On the other hand the rollforward completes successfully if I specify the end of log operation

Can someone please help me the cause of this error.

--- edit posted as answer:

Actually I was trying to practise roll forward recovery, the sample2 database is a test database with just one table. I took and online backup at 3 p.m then, inserted two rows in the table at 3.14 and 3.30 p.m. I wanted to bring the database as it was at 3.15 p.m after inserting row1 but I am uable to do it, all I can do is rollforward the database to end of logs.
I still don't get the reason I am unable to pit recover the db to 3.15pm

Comment: Have you checked the options in the error message `db2 ? SQL4970N` or  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic10.html#sql4970n   could it be just that " the point-in-time specified may actually be beyond any work performed against the database"

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep in mind that, by default, the `ROLLFORWARD` command operates using the UTC time zone.

Unless you’re working in UTC, you probably want to specify `USING LOCAL TIME` in your command:

```
rollforward database sample2 to 2018-09-01-15.16.00 using local time and stop;
```